# How to add existing .momd to a project in Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4

I have a project that includes a subproject.  The subproject has a Core Data model and generates a .momd "bundle."  I need that .momd bundle to be included in the main projects app bundle that is generated when the project is built.  The .momd file is generated, and is in the build directory, but I cannot see how to get it included in the final app bundle.

I can add the .momd as a file in the "Copy Bundle Resources" (by adding a reference to it to the main project in my Supporting Files group) but since the .momd is not a Finder level bundle, it adds it in as a directory and the .momd contents get copied into the app bundle, but not the .momd folder itself, so the system cannot find it when the app runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, after trying all sorts of things all afternoon, and searching with Google and Bing and inside SO, and not coming up with anything, soon after I post the question, I figure it out.

When adding the .momd file to the main app project (I added it to "Supporting Files" group), check "Create folder references for any added folders" and NOT "create groups for any added folders" (And also do not check "Copy items into destination group's folder" if the .momd is being generated in a sub-project)

Doing it that way makes the .momd gets copied into the app bundle...

Comment: Thank you for posting the correct answer after solving it by yourself!!